# Migrating to Lubuntu 19.10

Tags: unity, gnome, lubuntu, lxqt

I've installed the lubuntu-desktop package and love it. To save space, I'm wondering whether I can uninstall Gnome and unity. Is it safe to remove 'ubuntu-desktop' package? Are there any other packages I should install or remove to have a comfortable lubuntu experience without doing a fresh install?

Edit: 
On doing a dry-run purge of ubuntu-desktop, the following autoremovable packages were listed. Please advise as to which of them are necessary for the functioning of Ubuntu with lxqt.

> aisleriot app-install-data-partner apturl apturl-common baobab
>     branding-ubuntu brltty cheese deja-dup dmz-cursor-theme
>     duplicity espeak-ng-data fonts-noto-color-emoji gedit
>     gedit-common gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-4
>     gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gnome-calendar gnome-font-viewer
>     gnome-initial-setup gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines
>     gnome-screenshot gnome-session-canberra
>     gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
>     gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
>     gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-sudoku gnome-todo
>     gnome-todo-common gnome-video-effects gstreamer1.0-packagekit
>     gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps guile-2.2-libs gvfs-bin
>     ibus-table libatk-adaptor libbrlapi0.6 libdazzle-1.0-0
>     libdotconf0 libespeak-ng1 libgc1c2 libgnome-games-support-1-3
>     libgnome-games-support-common libgnome-todo libgtk2-perl
>     libgtksourceview-4-0 libgtksourceview-4-common libnotify-bin
>     libpango-perl libpcaudio0 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
>     libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libqqwing2v5 libraw19
>     libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport
>     librsync2 libsonic0 libspeechd2 libsysmetrics1 nautilus-share
>     network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu orca python3-bcrypt
>     python3-brlapi python3-fasteners python3-future
>     python3-gi-cairo python3-lockfile python3-louis
>     python3-monotonic python3-paramiko python3-pyatspi
>     python3-speechd seahorse shotwell shotwell-common simple-scan
>     sound-icons speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins
>     speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng ubuntu-desktop-minimal
>     ubuntu-report ubuntu-settings ubuntu-software
>     ubuntu-web-launchers usb-creator-gtk vino xbrlapi
>     xcursor-themes xdg-user-dirs-gtk yaru-theme-gtk
>     yaru-theme-icon yaru-theme-sound

Comment: I believe it's safe to remove `ubuntu-desktop` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/ubuntu-desktop) but I've not tested it.  If you want to be 100% safe I'd spin up a VM, install your system (ie. Ubuntu 19.10, add `lubuntu-desktop`, then remove `ubuntu-desktop` & reboot the VM and see how it performs). Your backup if you have problems is a re-install using "Manual Partitioning" and use existing partitions (no-format)

Comment: note that these `*ubuntu-desktop` packages are just meta-packages and uninstalling it will not necessarily remove any real package.... you need at least an `autoremove` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed ubuntu-desktop, and ran "apt autoremove". Computer still booting, lxqt environment is still working wonderfully.

Anybody else who tries it please note that some amount of duplicate software is nevertheless left behind, which can be uninstalled manually, including, but not limited to, Nautilus, file roller, Thunderbird, etc.