# Asus eee 32-bit netbook ca. 2008 runs very slow, especially connecting to the internet

Tags: 16.04, performance, ubuntu-netbook

> ASUS  Eee PC  Series 900
>   Intel Celeron M ULV 900MHz processor.
>   Integrated Intel GMA 900 GPU.
>   12GB of Flash-based storage (4GB onboard SSD and 8GB PCI-E mini card SSD)
>   1GB of DDR2 RAM (667MHz)
>   8.9-inch screen with 1024 x 600 resolution.
>
> Running  Ubuntu 16.04  LTS
>   Firefox -  current update

This 2008 netbook PC runs very slow, especially connecting to the internet.
What can be done to improve system processing speed?

Comment: This question was from long ago, but I'll add I used the following `asus eepc 1000HE (intel atom n270, 1gb, intel mobile 945gse integrated), wireless RT2790` to QA-test all releases of Lubuntu up to and including Lubuntu 19.04 (18.04 was last with LXDE, 18.10 & 19.04 were LXQt) which was the last release that had *i386* ISOs (atom n270 is 32-bit only). I found the old eeepc speed good though I was careful in not wasting resources (ie. choosing apps carefully; matching user apps with libs used by DE) & used streaming railway/music vids from youtube etc without issue. User app choices are key.

Answer (score 2):

Your PC unfortunately does not fulfill the minimum system requirements:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

I fear there is not very much you can do, given you want to run a "normal" Ubuntu distribution.

Maybe you could try Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which are both more lightweight than the standard Gnome desktop, but I think your PC still won't feel fast.

I am sure there are special distributions out there which are specialized for running on very old hardware, but I am not adept in this topic.

You could use the following link as a starting point in order to find a suitable distribution:

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/7ujlie/best_ultralite_linux_distro_for_an_asus_eee_pc_in/

Comment: How can I remove the 16.04 LTS and replace it with LXDE?  Using a ISO USB,  how can I remove all the current 16.04 LTS to save ssd  area?

Comment: I see two ways - either download lxde and install it from scratch or install lxde from within your current Linux environment. I suggest to create a new question, as the comment section is limited, both from text length and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems are the Ubuntu instructions for low powered CPUs without much memory and slow storage, but it's somewhat out of date, especially when it comes to [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me).  That 'flavour' of Ubuntu offers the LXDE desktop in [Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-i386.iso). That's the official desktop distribution which uses the least memory and runs the fastest, for you cannot run 64-bit operating systems on the eee.

You may push further by replacing LXDE with [LXQt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186320/migrating-to-lubuntu-19-10), an even lighter desktop with `sudo apt-get remove abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview alacarte bison blueman brltty-x11 catfish espeak exo-utils flex fonts-droid fonts-lyx gigolo gmusicbrowser gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs gthumb gthumb-data gtk2-engines-pixbuf indicator-application-gtk2 indicator-sound-gtk2 leafpad libabiword-2.9 libbison-dev libdigest-crc-perl libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfl-dev libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgstreamer-perl libgtk2-notify-perl libgtk2-trayicon-perl libgtkmathview0c2a libgtkspell0 libido-0.1-0 libindicate-gtk3 libintl-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs libkeybinder0 liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libnet-dbus-perl liboobs-1-5 libotr2 libots0 librarian0 libsexy2 libtagc0 libthunarx-2-0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtumbler-1-0 libunique-1.0-0 libvte-common libvte9 libwv-1.2-4 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util6 libxfcegui4-4 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en m4 orage parole pastebinit pavucontrol pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog pidgin-otr plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text python-configobj rarian-compat ristretto screensaver-default-images scrollkeeper shimmer-themes system-tools-backends tcl8.5 thunar thunar-archive-plugin thunar-data thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman ttf-droid tumbler tumbler-common xbrlapi xchat xchat-common xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-appfinder xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-indicator-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-volumed xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4 xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-default-settings xubuntu-desktop xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-wallpapers && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`.

However, that's only part of the story. Not only do you need to pay attention to the desktop in Linux, you also need to pay attention to your apps. Chrome is an absolute greedy hawg when it comes to CPU and memory use. Firefox is less so, but there are web browsers which are even less demanding. See http://itsfoss.com/open-source-browsers-linux and http://linux.com/tutorials/5-minimal-web-browsers-linux for a start.

http://wiki.dennyhalim.com/ubuntu-minimal-desktop and https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-ubuntu-1310/ are a few of many web pages which specialize in helping folks run lighter and faster still.

Comment: The last Ubuntu that ran acceptably on my 1G compute stick (+1G compressed swap) was End-Of-Life 14.04.  Tried Lubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, no tweaking, but too slow. Debian is OK, but AntiX (Debian based without systemd) and its lightweight set of apps is what seems the best fit for my for limited hardware.

Comment: Yeahbut, we're oblighed to talk Ubuntu + flavours here.